# Ubuntu crashes and shuts down under any heavy load

Tags: drivers, shutdown, overheating

Hi I am a total noob in Linux, i have literally used it first time about 4hr ago, so please don't grub the pitchforks if i will say something that would sound to you as extraordinarily dumb.

My problem is that each time my laptop overheats it`s shutdowns without any warning or errors.

The only additional drivers Linux has found is Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPU.

And the only weird behavior i have noticed is that on startup each time i see the message something like:

> /dev/sda1: clean, 291272/4292608 files, 480345/18174432 blocks

I believe it is checking hard drive for errors.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64 on laptop Asus Aspire-5738 , my main suspects is:
- the graphics card. It may be that this version of ubuntu does not support older Radeon graphics cards
I would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: I am not sure what's your question. It is not uncommon for overheating to cause shutdowns, and yes, you have to make sure the laptop does not overheat. Clean the fan, don't block the opening, etc.

Comment: No, sorry, i should have bean more specific, it is not that it shutdowns on overheating it is just that smallest rise in temperature is enough, for example i cannot even start up  the Intellij, not even speaking of using it, when on windows i have none of such problems. I am currently searching for some application that would measure the temperature of cpu, and would upload the results shortly

Comment: Lots of question here about monitoring cpu temp. Have you tried searching?

Comment: A machine shutting down happens like this when the CPU reaches a critical thermal level.  I had to replace the thermal paste on my CPU as well as clean out the fan and I was able to run my processor at ~20 degrees C cooler.     One could also run thermald, this will try some passive cooling techniques to stop the CPU from overheating, but it may end up scaling the CPU frequency down to an unusable level.  If that happens then it is a clear indication that there is a physical issue with the machine, e.g. fans clogged.

Comment: Yes it appears that I will have to clean it, my idle temperature is ~65 deg C. What is weird about it is how fast the temperature rises even watching a video on youtube increase the temperature up to 90 deg

Answer (score 0):

Well the answer was quite unexpected so i decided to shear it. It appears that the Aspire 5738 and a few others laptops of the similar versions, have bean tuned to work specifically with Win Vista. So after reading a shit ton of blog posts here is my suggestions:

Uninstall Ubuntu and reinstall windows, go to acer off page and download the update for bios. If your current version is lover then 1.34 this will resolve the problem up to the usable status, but your laptop is still gonna overheat so you still should clean it (as i did).

The more advanced steps appears to be to manually install latest VGA drivers, and make some additional holes for ventilation. I have not done neither of those and leave it up to you.