# How to diagnose crash/reboots under heavy load?

Tags: 20.04, crash, gpu

I have recently upgraded my PC to a relatively new (but bought used) motherboard  and a relatively new (also bought used) CPU (AMD Ryzen 5 3600) but kept the graphics card in (Radeon R9 270x). I did a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04.

Now the PC crashes and reboots under heavy CPU and graphic card load, almost exclusively in games (although they are older games that the PC should be able to handle). It usually happens some minutes after the graphics card fans sound like they've hit their highest RPM. The temperatures of CPU and graphics card go up to about 78-80 °C but no higher. I am suspecting it's an issue with the graphics card because it's also happened twice during dragging 3D objects in an interior design/CAD-like program (SweetHome3D from the Snap store).

However, I've tried running a GPU stress test (FurMark) concurrently with the `stress` command on all CPU cores/threads for some minutes (much longer than it usually takes the computer to crash in games) and it went fine. Temperatures again topped out at about 80 °C, so I don't think it's an overheating issue. I've also upgraded the PSU to a 550 W one which should be more than enough but it didn't solve the problem. I would be willing to upgrade the graphics card but considering current prices (and the fact that I didn't want a high-end gaming machine just a relatively future proof upgrade) I would like to rule out any other issues first.

How would I go about diagnosing this? What logs would I look at, what could the differences be between the games and the stress tests that I did? I know there have been similar questions but none have really helped me find the issue I'm having. They either reference [freezing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304535/ubuntu-20-04-keeps-freezing-on-huawei-laptop) (no rebooting), [thermal issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898884/ubuntu-crashes-and-shuts-down-under-any-heavy-load) or [faulty power supplies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1050498/what-does-it-mean-if-my-system-shuts-down-unexpectedly-with-no-message-in-the-lo) and I think I have ruled out the latter two. I also realise that this may not sound very Ubuntu-specific, but it's the system I'm running and I would want to diagnose it on.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Edit**

Here is the output of `free`. There are 4 GB of swap.

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15Gi       2.8Gi        10Gi        34Mi       2.1Gi        12Gi
Swap:         4.0Gi          0B       4.0Gi
```

**Edit 2**

Here is a paste of `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` as requested by user waltinator: https://pastebin.com/hkpk7BJi

Comment: See the logs leading to the crash `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e`. How much swap space have you? `free`. Read `man journalctl free mkswap swapon`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have added both the output of `free` as well as the journal. I tried forcing a crash with a GPU benchmark (Basemark GPU) as well as game that had crashed before (Satellite Reign) but had no luck this time. Another game (Ultimate Epic Battle Simulator) crashed nearly immediately but I can't really glean any useful information from the journal, it just seems to stop shortly before the crash. Swap seems to be okay too? Or should some be used?

Comment: Just as a clarification (because I can't edit the last comment anymore): Running the game caused a reboot, as per the problem description, it didn't just crash.

Comment: A short update in case anyone else has any ideas: I've had a few more crashes/reboots. None of the logs (kernel, syslog, dmesg) show anything interesting before the reboot, they just stop at whatever the last regular entry would be.
I'm wondering if there is anyway to narrow down whether the GPU is the likely culprit or not but I'm so far I'm coming up empty. Any help would be appreciated!